# Why is specific volume constant in a rigid closed tank?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, phase-transition, volume

If we do have a liquid-vapor mixture in a rigid tank, and we cool it down to be a compressed liquid, in this case, why do we assume constant specific volume: $v_1 = v_2$?

We know that the density of a liquid is much  higher than that of a vapor; then from

$${\rm density} = \frac{1}{v}$$

$v_2$ must be smaller!!

Answer (score 1):

The volume of the tank is constant, and is related to the amounts of vapor and liquid in the tank and to their specific volumes by $$V_T=m_Lv_L+m_Vv_V$$If we divide this by the total mass of liquid and vapor in the tank, which is also constant, we get:$$\bar{v}=\frac{V_T}{(m_L+m_V)}=\frac{m_Lv_L+m_Vv_V}{(m_L+m_V)}$$where $\bar{v}$ is the average specific volume of the mixture.  This is the quantity which is constant.

Answer (score 0):

The total specific volume of the liquid vapor mixture, $v$ (m$^{3}$/kg) is given by

$$v=xv_{g}+(1-x)v_f$$

where

$v_g$ = specific volume of the gas (vapor) component (m$^{3}$/kg)

$v_f$ = specific volume of the fluid (liquid) component (m$^{3}$/kg)

$x$ = quality of the mixture, i.e., the fraction of the mixture that is vapor.

You can obtain the values of $v_g$ and $v_f$ from the saturated steam tables for the saturation temperature of the mixture.

When you cool the mixture down, the quality $x$ (fraction of the mixture that is a vapor) decreases. The total specific volume remains constant.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [specific volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_volume), $\nu$, of a substance is the reciprocal of its density. So long as the density of the liquid remains constant, than the specific volume will remain constant. If cooling the liquid changes the volume significantly, it's probably not a simple chemical process and we have to be more careful with analyzing it. Most liquids you will ever encounter will closely match their density for all temperatures that the liquid is capable of existing at.